# Can I pick $\{\phi_n\} \subset C_0^\infty$ uniformely bounded and converging to a certain $1_A \in L^p$, where $A$ is measurable and compact?

Tags: real-analysis

I want to use it for an alternative proof of [What locally integrable function $f$ satisfies $\int_a^ b f(x) \phi'(x)dx=0 $ for each $\phi \in C_0^\infty(a,b)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106619/what-locally-integrable-function-f-satisfies-int-a-b-fx-phixdx-0-fo)

I need to pick a $\phi_n$ sufficiently close to $1_A$ but such that $||\phi_n+1_A||_\infty$ is not too big.

Comment: Small and bounded are different adjectives! In general you cannot have a uniform approximation by means of compactly supported functions. However, boundedness should be easier to get.

Comment: I edited my question so it's more clear. Bounding an only $\phi$ should be quite easy. I want to bound all of them uniformly after certain $n$. I guess I can't.

Comment: What is $A$? what does "not so big" mean? Do you want to pick a sequence (as in the body of the question), or are you given such a sequence and you want to know if $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is bounded (as in the title)?

Comment: I'm happy if I can do this with $A$ a closed, bounded interval of $\mathbb{R}$. My title question was wrong [again]. I want what's in the body of it.

Comment: Still, what does not so big mean. And please edit your question.

Comment: @ArcticChar, I edited my question 4 hours ago, when I answered you.

Answer (score 2):

$\phi$ is a [Schwartz function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) (because it is in $C_0^\infty$). This implies there exists a constant $c>0$ such that
$$
|\phi(x)|<\frac{c}{|x|^2}
$$ for all x.

Maybe that helps?

Comment: It helps! But it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I just edited my question so it's clearer.